# Adding hyphens in domain name registrations

Tags: dns

I wanted to register a domain name for myself but as usual could not get exactly the name I wished for. 
Ex: 11minutes.com was what I wanted.

But I found a very similar one with a hyphen in between.
Ex:11-minutes.com

Are there any disadvantages to buying this domain ?

Comment: Adding tag names domain and domains is mapping to dns itself. Can you kindly re-adjust the tags appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

One down side is that people looking for the 11-minutes version might type the other variant into their browser address bar and go to the wrong site.

Another is that if the version already registered is a trademark in the same business as you, they could decide you're infringing and have your domain taken away.

It's better to have something distinct in most cases.